# xUnit tests are failed with shared static data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have several unit tests that use some static class, for example:

```
public static class Utility
{
    private static Data data;

    public static void Init(Data data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static void Process()
    {
        // Some actions that changes this.data (not reference, just inner Values)
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        Values.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Each unit test initializes Data instance and passes it to Utility:

```
[Fact]
public void UnitTest1()
{
    var data = new Data();
    data.Add("val1");
    Utility.Init(data);

    Utility.Process();

    // check changed data instance
}

[Fact]
public void UnitTest2()
{
    var data = new Data();
    data.Add("another_val1");
    data.Add("another_val2");
    Utility.Init(data);

    Utility.Process();

    // check changed data instance
}
```

If I run each test separately then there is no problem - no failed tests.
But If I run tests sequentially then one of the unit tests is failed because Utility.data contains instance from previous test (for a short time) despite of Utility.Init call.
If I run tests through command line (tests performs very fast) then big part of tests is failed most likely for the same reason. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Because of the nature of the static utility all the tests are accessing a shared static resource which can have negative effects as already experience. I suggest making the utility class an instance class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the nature of the static utility all the tests are accessing a shared static resource which can have negative effects as already experience. I suggest making the utility class an instance class

```
public class Utility
{
    private Data data;

    public Utility(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void Process() {
        // Some actions that changes this.data (not reference, just inner Values)
    }
}
```

Which an example test would look like

```
[Fact]
public void UnitTest1() {
    //Arrrange
    var data = new Data();
    data.Add("val1");
    var subject = new Utility(data);

    //Act
    subject.Process();

    //Assert
    // check changed data instance
}
```

I suspect that the initil issue was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that the Utility is also being used as a static dependency in production, which is a code smell.

In that case abstract the static utility class

```
public interface IUtility {
    void Process(Data data);
}
```

and refactor the implementation

```
public class Utility : IUtility {

    public void Process(Data data) {
        // Some actions that changes this.data (not reference, just inner Values)
    }
}
```

Which would result in a test looking like

```
[Fact]
public void UnitTest1() {
    //Arrrange
    var data = new Data();
    data.Add("val1");
    var subject = new Utility();

    //Act
    subject.Process(data);

    //Assert
    // check changed data instance
}

[Fact]
public void UnitTest2() {
    var data = new Data();
    data.Add("another_val1");
    data.Add("another_val2");
    var subject = new Utility();

    //Act
    subject.Process(data);

    //Assert
    // check changed data instance
}
```

The `IUtility` would be injected into dependent classes as needed, which would make the resulting code more SOLID.

Comment: I tried not to use static at all and got the same effect. Problem is not in a static. Possibly in copying an object reference: `subject.Process(data);` and side effects

Comment: @user190794 if using a new instance there is no way for a previous test to have access to data from another instance

Comment: @user190794 does `Process` use some shared resource?

Comment: Property `Values` from `Data` (see my example) was static, this is my mistake. Agree with @Nkosi suggestion